# View duplicating parent state when I don't want it to

Tags: android, listview

I have an XML file that defines the layout of a row in the list.  The layout is, at the outer-most level, a LinearLayout.  Inside, there is another LinearLayout which takes up the right 30 dips of the row.

I have a drawable set as the background resource of the outer LinearLayout.  This serves as the selector for the row.  The row is normally white.  When you click it, it is green.

I also have a drawable set as the background resource of the inner LinearLayout which takes up the right 30 dips of the row.  That drawable looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/light_blue_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/light_blue_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/light_blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/light_blue_pressed" />
</selector>
```

I have added an OnClickListener to this inner LinearLayout so, when you click on it, the color of the LinearLayout changes from light_blue to light_blue_pressed.

However, clicking anywhere else on the row (read: outer LinearLayout) should not change the color of the inner LinearLayout, and it does.

I have added the `android:duplicateParentState` option to my inner LinearLayout with a value of `false` and the problem is still occurring.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_warning_level"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_light_blue"
        android:duplicateParentState="false" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your selector only to inner `LinearLayout` and remove selector from your `ListView`. You can remove it by calling `listView.setSelector(null)` or in xml `android:listSelector="@null"`

Comment: But I want a selector on my ListView.  I have another selector which I use for the entire row (the white space, which makes up the majority of the row).  The 30dip blue space is essentially a button.  Clicking on that button takes you somewhere.  Clicking anywhere else on the row selects the row.